# 'Index' is not callable

Tags: python, web-scraping, indexing

```
while (x < go):


url = "https://www.shoppingwesbite.com/search?=product" + input_a
headers = {'User-Agent': 'my user agent here'}
ok = get(url, headers=headers)
data = BeautifulSoup(ok.content, 'html.parser')

price = data.find_all('div', {"class" : "css-rey619"})[x].get_text()
title = data.find_all('div', {"class" : "css-398hol"})[x].get_text()
reviews = data.find_all('span', {'class':'css-402phy'})[x].get_text()
```

I have included this piece of code from my web scraper and it essentially just pulls the first 10 results on a shopping website for a product inputted by the user. Now, most of the time it works but sometimes it returns the error that says the index is not callable for the "reviews" variable because I think it's trying to pull a review for a product that doesn't have a review yet. I don't know how to get around this and would appreciate any suggestions/ideas on what I could try. I was thinking on making some logic statement that checks if the listing has a review or not and outputting it if it does, but I don't know how to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: you can add a code to check if there is no review ignore that before the loop starts

Comment: How would I achieve this? What type of statement would I use? Is there any inbuilt method in python for this?

Comment: can you post some minimal reproducible code here?

Comment: Would using the in-built function callable() work?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of the reviews, if it is zero you got empty review.

```
for i in range(len(reviews)):
    if len(reviews[i]) == 0:
         print("you got empty review now you can easily remove it")
```